# How can i use dtsExec command in stored procedure to execute ssis package by passing entire configuration from a table?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, msdn, dtexec

I am using given command line to execute ssis packages in sp in sql server.

```
SET @dtsExecCmd = @DTSEXECCMDPATH + ltrim(rtrim(@ssisPkgFilePath)) + '" /CONFIGFILE "' + ltrim(rtrim(@ssisCommonConfigPath)) + '"'

EXEC @result = master..xp_cmdshell @dtsExecCmd
```

where,

```
@DTSEXECCMDPATH = 'G:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft SQL Server"\110\DTS\Binn\dtexec /F "'


@ssisPkgFilePath = '\\dtsx package path\package.dtsx'

@ssisCommonConfigPath =
'\\CommonConfigurationpath\Configuration.dtsConfig'
```

Now i want to execute the same package by passing the configuration(present in `Configuration.dtsConfig` earlier) from table, how do i have to edit this command line if `@config` contains configuration from table.

Comment: _What version of SSIS?_ From SQL 2012 onwards there is a more sophisticated T-SQL API which means you don't need to resort to insecure `xp_cmdshell` hacks.

Comment: If you're still using `.dtsConfig` then I guess it's an older version. You need to change your _package_ to read its config from a database table, not a dtsConfig file. This is a change made in the package. But really, this is _very old_ technology now. You should definitely not be building anything new in this version.

Comment: Oh.. i see `110` in your bin path so this is SQL 2012? You really need to upgrade to SSISDB and project deployment.

Comment: yes nick this is sql server 2012 and ssis is also really old ...its been in use since long

Comment: Nick as of now i'll be using sql server 2012(or 2017 in near future) only ,can you please suggest what actually has to be updated in ssis packages , so that i can read configuration in dtexec command from table(encrypted), and how big that change would be ?  thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well the first step is to go and investigate the configurations area in SSIS in SSDT / BIDS. Also read this. https://mikedavissql.com/2011/10/04/using-configuration-tables-in-ssis-20082005/amp/

Comment: hi nick, can i do the required configuration changes in already existing ssis packages ? I think packages are made with SSDT 2008.

Comment: also why do we need to change package when we are executing dtexec command in stored procedure?

Comment: currently we are using <DTS:ConnectionManager DTS:ConnectionString=""; <DTS:Password  DTS:Name="password" </DTS:Password   </DTS:ConnectionManager>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are not going to upgrade to project deployment for these package and stick with package deployment.

There is no `DTEXEC` command line switch that lets you define a SQL Server table to load a config from.

The easiest way to use package configuration from a SQL Server table is to open the package up in SSDT, go the SSIS/Package Configurations and set it up. Then you don't need to pass anything on the `DTEXEC` command line at all.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/package-configurations?view=sql-server-2014#sql-server

If you don't want to make a package change and you insist on passing it through `DTEXEC` then I suppose you could write a wrapper that pulls the config data out of a table and one by one applies those configs using the `/SET` switch.

But I really encourage and recommend you to upgrade these packages to the project deployment model. Don't waste your time with this old method. You're just introducing technical debt.

You should also know that `xp_cmdshell` is generally considered to be a security issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info . One more thing i wanted to know was if i choose to use package configuration from sql server table, can i keep the connection string in table as encrypted ?

Comment: Not sure - you’d need to experiment. I always try to use windows authentication so nothing needs to be encrypted.

Comment: and we can set the authentication type while setting up configuration for packge ?

Comment: Authentication type is defined in the connection string. Which is defined at design time in SSDT and optionally in a config.